# How can I properly handle Vue slots in Storybook

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, storybook, vuejs-slots

I'm trying to get Vue slots working in Storybook. I'm currently at Storybook v7 beta release, because there were changes that made it better for our project. We use Vue 3 with vite. We also use Typescript everywhere.

The problem is that Storybook doesn't seem to give an easy way to add slot content. The only way is through the args object, and even then you need something like this to make it work correctly:

```
const meta: Meta<typeof Modal> = {
    title: 'Componenten/Modal',
    component: Modal,
    render: (args: any) => ({
        components: { Modal },
        setup() {
            return { args };
        },
        template:
            '<Modal v-bind="args">' +
            '<template v-if="args.data" v-slot:data>' +
            '<div v-html="args.data" />' +
            '</template>' +
            '</Modal>',
    }),
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Modal>;

export const Modal: Story = {
    args: {
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        show: true,
        actions: [
            {
                buttonType: ButtonType.Remove,
                label: 'Yes, remove',
                link: () => {},
            },
            {
                label: 'Cancel',
                link: () => {},
            },
        ],
        data: "<a href={'/test'}>Hello world</a>",
    },
};
```

I do think that this is ugly and should have an easier option, but I'm not sure there's an alternative?

Also, the slot names are not in the types of the args object, so with this code, typescript gives a TS2322 error that the slot name is not a property on args. This can work by using any, but that is something I'd rather not do.

Does anyone know a better solution for this?